# Execute .bat cmd Commands after entering blocking mode

Tags: batch-file, command-line, redis, command-prompt

There are few commands which I often have to execute one by one and repeated multiple times for project development as

```
1) ----Open Command Prompt
2) cd "C:\Program Files\Redis"
3) redis-cli.exe -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6666
4) 127.0.0.1:6666> flushdb
5) 127.0.0.1:6666> select 1
6) 127.0.0.1:6666> flushdb
7) ----Close Command Prompt
```

So, I thought of creating a batch file like

```
@echo off
cd "C:\Program Files\Redis"
redis-cli.exe -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6666
flushdb
select 1
flushdb
```

But the problem is that once the execution enters redis-cli.exe the further commands are blocked. It stays like

```
127.0.0.1:6666>_
```

And waiting for commands. . I want to know how can I supply those remaining commands to this redis-cli.exe and execute.

I played with commands like run/cmd/start and others but no use.

I could not suggest a better Title for this question because I didn't know what to call this kind of blocking behavior or even if it is possible. If anyone comes with a better name, please do update so others can be benefited.

Comment: may be `(echo flushdb & echo select 1 & echo flushdb) | "c:\program files\redis\redis-cli.exe" -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6666`

Comment: @elzooilogico I think your suggestion is working. I tried it. But I am not sure if it is really working because the command prompt opens and then immediately closed. I can see there is something written but I can't see if it executed or not. Is there any way to stop the command from getting closed after exection?

Comment: The command prompt is getting closed. But I just checked it's working. Thanks Alot. Salute to hero who answer in comments.

Comment: Either run the command directly from the Command Prompt window, or run the batch file from the Command Prompt window. Alternatively, add another line with either `pause` or `timeout -1` on it then double-click the batch file to run it. If it doesn't work you may be able to create a text file containing your commands on each line, then try running your executable using that file as input via **`<"file.txt"`**.

Comment: @Compo Thanks Compo. That solved my problem. It was really nice of you both.

Comment: Ok. So should I delete this question? May be someone else can be benefited by this?

Answer (score 0):

You could check `redis-cli.exe /?` if there is any documentation about how you can invoke it from the command line and have it execute a command sequence at once. Maybe there is some switch needed like `/C "mycommand1 & mycommand2 & mycommand3"` as known from cmd.exe (I don`t know any details about the Redis CLI).

The "blocking" you observed is because `redis-cli` opens up a command prompt itself to process user input. Much like a `telnet` would do or a `wmic` or `diskpart`. Typically you can leave those prompts with the `exit` command. This also works for `cmd.exe` itself. But not for telnet ;) It is some kind of mystery to me how to quit from that thing...
The "inside redis mode" is recognizable by the `127.0.0.1:6666>` prefix instead of the usual `C:\your\path\here>` prompt presented by a default "cmd.exe".

The term would be "blocking" after "prompting for input" or "reading from standard in".
You were not too far off and provided a decent title, I would say.

Comment: to solve the mystery: `quit` will terminate `telnet` (see [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/telnet.html))